# How do I sum rows in Business Objects based on multiple same dimensions?

Tags: sum, aggregate, business-objects

I have a report in Business Objects like below.
Name DOB    DATE     Balance
Test 121212 01012010 10
Test 121212 02022012 10
Nest 050599 01012010 20
Nest 050599 02022012 10

I would like to create a new variable which sums the Balance based on NAME DOB only (exclude DATE).

The results would be:
Name DOB    DATE     Balance SumBalance
Test 121212 01012010 10      20
Test 121212 02022012 10      20
Nest 050599 01012010 20      30
Nest 050599 02022012 10      30

The results would be:
Name DOB    DATE     Balance SumBalance
Test 121212 01012010 10      20
Test 121212 02022012 10      20
Nest 050599 01012010 20      30
Nest 050599 02022012 10

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
SumBalance = Sum([Balance]) In ([Name]; [DOB])
```

Hope that helps.